# Will be valid an activerecord intance passed as parameter to mailer that will send later?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activejob

I'm passing as parameter a instance of ActiveRecord to a Mailer through:

```
SomeMailer.with(my_instance: someActiveRecordInstance).welcome_mail.send_later
```

And then, **later** when the email will send I do some stuff inside the Mailer like:

```
my_instance = params[:my_instance]
name = my_instance.name
lastname = my_intance.lastname
```

And here my question: **will the ActiveRecord passed valid after the request finish and the mailer executes later (maybe another thread I think)?**

I can't imagine what would be happen. But yet I'm thinking maybe I should better pass the **`id`** of the instance and then retrieve it again when I need it inside the mailer or simply passing the object instance would be ok?

Comment: "I can't imagine what would be happen" - looks like you have all the code. Why not just try it?

Comment: But yes, passing an id _will_ work, for sure.

Comment: https://thoughtbot.com/blog/action-mailer-and-active-job-sitting-in-a-tree

Comment: thanks for comments. I read the blog you posted @Sergio and it becomes clear. I can, but its a better practice to pass simple data, then better simply the id.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass it but as you mentioned, you don't know what happen at the time the mail is sending, maybe that record already deleted and it will raise errors. Best practice with `delayed job` or `worker` is just passing the id then in the job we can find the record at the time it is executed

Answer (score 1):

This is not a good practice. Considering,

1. The instance could have been updated by the time it is accessed in the mailer.
2. If that serialized ActiveRecord model instance has big/lengthy columns(TEXT or json columns maybe), it could break due to the maximum job size.

Second points depends on the adapter used for ActiveJob though. 
For example SQS has message size limit of 256 KB

Comment: Large payload due to object's serialized form should not be a problem. I am 90% sure that actionmailer will also use GlobalID (same as ActiveJob). See this, for example: https://thoughtbot.com/blog/action-mailer-and-active-job-sitting-in-a-tree